# How To Get Photo IDs from Flickr API?

Tags: json, jsonp, flickr

I am trying to use JQUERY to grab photos from a Flickr group. I can get back valid JSON, but can't figure out how to get access to the actual photos. The JSON that is returned contains an empty list where I would expect photos.

So when I plug this into the browser:

```
http://api.flickr.com/services/rest?method=flickr.groups.pools.getPhotos&api_key=2c4df0060561b03151cda6a1xxxx&format=json&group_id=919043@N22&jsoncallback=?
```

The json that I get back is this:

```
 jsonFlickrApi({"photos":{"page":1, "pages":1, "perpage":100, "total":"6", "photo":[]}, "stat":"ok"})
```

It seems like it knows that there are six photos, but the photo list is empty. I assume I am missing a step. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I just pasted that same url into Firefox (using my own Flickr api key) and it worked fine, I got (anonymized):

```
jsonFlickrApi(
  {"photos": {"page":1, "pages":1, "perpage":100, "total":"6", "photo":
   [{"id": "292744xxxx", "owner":"11363xxx@xxx", "secret":"f084efxxxx",
     "server":"3xxx", "farm":4, "title":"Pink Floyd", "ispublic":1,
     "isfriend":0, "isfamily":0, "ownername":"moexxxxx", "dateadded":"122358xxxx"},
   {"id":
    ...
   }
    ...
  },
  "stat":"ok"})
```